# Attach one element from a DataFrame in sparkR

Tags: r, sparkr

I have a DataFrame in sparkR called 'data'. 'Data' contains 'user', 'amount_spent' and 'amount_won'.
I want to calculate balance= amount_spent - amount_won for user 1.

```
y <- filter(data, data$user==1)
```

Now I calculate the sums

```
yn <- agg(groupBy(y, "user"), amount_spent="sum", amount_won="sum")
```

Now I calculate the balance for user 1

```
ynn <- withColumn(yn, "balance", yn[[3]] - yn[[2]])
```

And this all gives me a correct results however I want to attach "balance" and have it as an integer from 'ynn' which is a DataFrame. How can I do that? And if I want to do this for 100 users I need to do the same thing 100 times I assume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be missing something, but why not do:

```
## The data set is now `data` not yn
yn = agg(groupBy(data, "user"), amount_spent="sum", amount_won="sum")
```

When you now calculate the balance, you have it per user

```
ynn = withColumn(yn, "balance", yn[[3]] - yn[[2]])
```